# Mapbox programmatically add polygon with different heights

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

We are trying to create a polygon programmatically in typescript using mapbox gl. But starting height and ending height of the polygon will be different to create a slope. Please let me know is there any way to achieve this requirement.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox GL JS does not support 3D shapes with sloping surfaces. You could use something like three.js (via ThreeBox) to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you Steve for you suggestion. I have checked and it seems box is possible using three.js but slope is kind of not possible. Can you pls help me out some example if possible